# Ajax request not sent when the server is offline

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, settimeout, setinterval

I have a webpage with which users can reboot his server. Once the user clicks "reboot" button he sees a temporary page saying "rebooting please wait...".

I want this "rebooting..." page automatically check if the server gets rebooted and redirect the user to the main page once the server is online again. Below is my attempt to achieve this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Rebooting, please wait...</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function checkPageReady() {
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open('POST', '/', true);
   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
      window.location = '/';
   };
   request.send(null);
  }
  function checkPageReadyInLoop() {
   setInterval(checkPageReady, 1000);
  }
 </script>

</head>
<body onload="setTimeout(checkPageReadyInLoop, 10000);">
 Rebooting, please wait...
</body>
</html>
```

Basically the page waits 10 seconds and starts pinging the server with Ajax request every second. When the server responds the main page gets shown.

However what I see via Chrome Developer Tools is that while the server is offline (e.g. rebooting) no Ajax requests are ever sent. If I fake reboot (so the server does not get offline) everything works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got what's going on here. The server returns this page to a user and immediately starts rebooting, so the page might not gets fully loaded in the user's browser. Since the page is not fully loaded  is not fired and Ajax checks are never started.

I fixed this by moving the call setTimeout(checkPageReadyInLoop, 10000) to the end of  section. I tested it in Chrome, IE and FF and it works as magic.

I wonder whether this is a proper solution?